# Precise asymptotic of diophantine approximation

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

I know that every irrational number $\xi$ can be approximated by rational numbers in such a way that
$$
\left| \xi - \frac{p}{q} \right| \leq \frac{c}{q^2}
$$
for infinitely many choices of $p$ and $q$. Here $c>0$ is some constant that depends on $\xi$.

My question is: for what (irrational) numbers can we have a precise asymptotic estimate, namely
$$
\frac{c_1}{q^2} \leq \left| \xi - \frac{p}{q} \right| \leq \frac{c_2}{q^2}
$$
as $q \to +\infty$?

**Edit**

My question comes from the following problem:

> Does there exist a cluster point for the sequence $n \mapsto 2n \{n\xi \}-n$? Here $\xi$ is an irrational number and $\{.\}$ denotes the fractional part of a real number.

If I assume that $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a cluster point, in particular for every $a<x$ and every $b>x$ there are infinitely many integers $p$ and $q$ such that
$$
\frac{2a}{q^2} < \xi - \frac{p}{q} < \frac{2b}{q^2}.
$$
Furthermore, $p = [q\xi]$, the integer part of $q\xi$.

At this point I am kind of stuck. I can't understand if the answer is positive or negative, although I suspect that it is more probably negative.

Comment: I suppose you mean for the double inequality to hold for infinitely many fractions $p/q$?

Comment: Yes, along some subsequence of integers.

Comment: Unless you assume $p,q$ relatively prime, you can choose $c_2=c$ from the first inequality and $c_1=c/4$. To sketch why it works, take any fraction satisfying $|\xi-p/q|<c/q^2$. If $|\xi-p/q|<c/4q^2$, then replace $p/q$ by $2p/2q$, and repeat until the double inequality works.

Comment: @Wojowu It seems to me that $c_1$ and $c_2$ cannot be both close to a fixed number different than zero, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

One useful characterization is: if and only if the coefficients in the continued fraction expansion of $\xi$ are bounded ($c_1$ and $c_2$ can be bounded in terms of the minimal and maximal coefficient). In particular, this is true when the expansion is periodic, i.e. when $\xi$ is a quadratic irrational.

One more useful pieceful information: if $c_1>1/3$, then there are countably many such $\xi$'s (each equivalent to a quadratic irrational occurring in the Markoff spectrum), while if $c_1=1/3$, then there are already continuum many (pairwise inequivalent) such $\xi$'s. Here equivalence is meant under the action of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ by fractional linear transformations.

**Clarification.** My response focused on a classical version of the problem, in which we try to achieve the lower bound for all $q$'s with $c_1$ as large as possible, while we try to achieve the upper bound for infinitely many $q$'s with $c_2$ as small as possible.

Comment: Per what OP said in the comments, they meant the double inequality to hold for infinitely many $p/q$, not that the left inequality holds for all $p/q$. However, your answer still contains neat results, so I advise you to keep it, but add how you understood OP's question.

Comment: @Wojowu: Thanks, I will clarify my response.

Comment: @GHfromMO It is very interesting. Can you please read my edit, where I try to be more precise about my question?

Comment: Can't you have uncountably many $\xi$ corresponding to the same element of the Markov spectrum?

Comment: @DouglasZare: I think no, since $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is countable. Two $\xi$'s are equivalent if and only if their continued fraction expansions are the same apart from finitely many coefficients and a shift of the coefficients.

Comment: @DouglasZare: Note also that by an element in the Markov spectrum I meant the quadratic irrational $\sqrt{9-4m^{-2}}$, where $m$ is a Markov number.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still missing something. For large enough elements of the spectrum (maybe only greater than the critical 4.5278?), I think you can have an uncountable collection of reals with the same lim sup of approximation efficiency. Say, choose blocks A and B, and any simple continued fraction built from an infinite string of A and B blocks such that each finite pattern occurs infinitely often should have the same lim sup. I think you are saying that something prevents that lim sup from being less than $3$, that only very special sequences occur then that can't be built that way.

Comment: Given $[a_0; a_1, a_2,...]$, we're looking at $\limsup_k a_k + [0;a_{k+1},a_{k+2},...] + [0;a_{k-1},a_{k-2},...,a_1]$, right? If we let $a_{n^2+\epsilon_n}=1$ and $a_n=2$ otherwise, where each $\epsilon_n \in \{0,1\}$, that gives uncountably many reals with lim sup efficiency of $2+1/\sqrt{2}+1/(1+\sqrt{2}) = 3.121$. Maybe why this is greater than $3$ is clear from some perspective I don't have yet.

Comment: @DouglasZare: We talk about different things. Of course the same limsup (or sup), when it is at most $1/3$, can be attained by continuum many (pairwise inequivalent) $\xi$'s. This harmonizes with my response. If the limsup (or sup) exceeds $1/3$, then $\xi$ is equivalent (in a certain sense) to $\sqrt{9-4m^{-2}}$ with $m$ a Markov number, and the limsup (or sup) is given in terms of this $m$, and there are countably many such $\xi$'s.

Answer (score 2):

Given $(p,q)$ and $\alpha$, let the *normalized error* of the approximation be $q^2|\xi - \frac{p}{q}|$. My interpretation of the question is whether there are $c_1,c_2 \gt 0$ so that every irrational number has infinitely many approximations whose normalized errors are in $[c_1,c_2]$.

As Wojowu comments, given one of the infinitely many convergents $p/q$ to the simple continued fraction for $\xi$, if $p/q$ is too close, you can make it worse by multiplying $p$ and $q$ by the same factor $d$. This doesn't change the quotient but it increases the normalized error of the approximation by a factor of $d^2$. If you choose $c_2$ so that it is achievable infinitely often (e.g., $1/\sqrt{5}$) then any convergent that is too good can be spoiled to have a normalized error in $[c_2/4,c_2]$.

If you require that $p/q$ is reduced, you can still construct infinitely many rational approximations whose normalized errors are in a uniform fixed interval, even when the coefficients of the simple continued fraction increase such as

$$\frac{e+1}{e-1} = 2+\cfrac{1}{6 + \cfrac{1}{10+\cfrac{1}{14+...}}}$$

There are infinitely many convergents to the simple continued fraction. If the coefficient $a_n$ is $1$ so $p_{n+1}/q_{n+1} = (p_n+p_{n-1})/(q_n+q_{n-1})$, then the convergent $p_n/q_n$ has a normalized error between $1/3$ and $1$: Since $\alpha$ is between $(p_n+p_{n-1})/(q_n+q_{n-1})$ and $(2p_n+p_{n-1})/(2q_n+q_{n-1})$, $|\alpha - p_n/q_n|$ is at least $1/(2q_n^2+q_nq_{n-1}) \ge 1/(3q_n^2)$, and of course it is at most $1/q_n^2$. If the coefficient $a_n$ is not $1$, then $(p_n+p_{n-1})/(q_n+q_{n-1})$ is not a convergent, so its normalized error is at least $1/2$, but its normalized error is not too large. The first $n$ convergents to $\xi$ are also convergents to $(p_n+p_{n-1})/(q_n+q_{n-1})$, so it is not far away and the denominator is less than twice $q_n$.

$$\begin{eqnarray}\left|\xi -\frac{p_n+p_{n-1}}{q_n+q_{n-1}}\right| &\le& \left|\xi - \frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|+\left|\frac{p_n}{q_n} - \frac{p_n+p_{n-1}}{q_n+q_{n-1}}\right|\newline &\le& \frac{1}{q_n(2q_n+q_{n-1})} + \frac{1}{q_n(q_n+q_{n-1})}\newline &\le& \frac{2}{q_n(q_n+q_{n-1})} \newline &\le& \frac{4}{(q_n+q_{n-1})^2}.\end{eqnarray}$$

So, if $a_n \gt 1$, the relative error of $(p_n+p_{n-1})/(q_n+q_{n-1})$ is between $1/2$ and $4$. For any irrational $\xi$, there are infinitely many reduced approximations with normalized errors between $1/3$ and $4$.

Comment: According to my edit, my question seems to be equivalent to the following: *given* $a$ and $b$ arbitrarily close to some (positive) number $x$, do there exist infinitely many integers $m$ and $n$ such that $$a \leq n^2 \left( \xi - \frac{m}{n} \right)$$ and $$n \left( \xi - \frac{m}{n} \right) < \frac{1}{2}?$$ Hence the question is related to your normalized error, and - roughly - I am asking if this error can converge to some positive number.

Comment: @Siminore: Since there are infinitely many normalized errors in an interval, there must be limit points.

Comment: Okay, but I don't think this is enough. To reverse your argument, it seems to me that $p$ must be something special: the integer part of $q \xi$.

Comment: @Siminore: That's not a particularly special condition on a good approximation to $\xi$. For convergents, it means that the index $n$ is even, since those are the approximations slightly below $\xi$ while the odd convergents are slightly above $\xi$. There are infinitely many even indices.