# On cluster points of a particular sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, diophantine-approximation

This is the sequel of [a previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237140/precise-asymptotic-of-diophantine-approximation).

Let us consider the sequence 
$$
\xi_n = 2n \{n\xi\}-n,
$$
where $\xi>0$ is a given real irrational number and $\{\cdot\}$ is the fractional part.

> Do there exist converging subsequences of $\{\xi_n\}_n$ to *finite* real numbers?

According to [an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/237184/23476), a necessary condition for the existence of cluster points is satisfied: the *normalized error*
$$
q^2 \left| \xi - \frac{p}{q} \right|
$$
is bounded with respect to $p$, $q \in \mathbb{N}$ and contains infinitely many different terms. However, it does not seem clear that the convergence of the normalized error along a subsequence entails the convergence of a subsequence of $\xi_n$, because $p$ and $q$ are not arbitrary integers. As far as I understand, diophantine approximation theory is not an obstruction. But is the answer affirmative? It is affirmative only for some class of irrational numbers?

More precisely, we have to produce (if any) a real number $x$ such that, for every $\epsilon>0$ we have for infinitely many integers $n$
$$
\left|
n^2 \left(\xi - \frac{[n\xi]}{n}\right) - 
\frac{x+n}{2}
\right|
<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

An experimental result.

Take $\xi=\sqrt{2}$.

At least up to $n=706248$, I got subsequence of $8$ terms 
converging roughly to $C= -1.59\ldots$.

The subsequence coincides so far with [OEIS A106328 Numbers j such that 8*(j^2) + 9 = k^2 for some positive number k](https://oeis.org/A106328).

Their $a(n)$ corresponds to $n$ in $\xi_n$ and $\sqrt{2}$ is in the comments.

Convergence also holds for $a(100)$ (76 decimal digits) from OEIS.

With high precision $C= -9\sqrt{2}/8$.

pari/gp session, bugs will invalidate the answer:

```
? \p 10000
realprecision = 10018 significant digits (10000 digits displayed)
? phi=sqrt(2.0);for(n=1,706248,a=2*n*frac(n*phi)-n;if(abs(round(a))==2,print1(n,",",)));
3,18,105,612,3567,20790,121173,706248

? phi=sqrt(2.0);for(n=1,706248,a=2*n*frac(n*phi)-n;if(abs(round(a))==2,print([n,precision(a,1)])));
 [3, -1.5441558772842891216]
 [18, -1.5896115822344083765]
 [105, -1.5909496732541739228]
 [612, -1.5909890629760832406]
 [3567, -1.5909902225012345007]
 [20790, -1.5909902566344680254]
 [121173, -1.5909902576392566059]
 [706248, -1.5909902576688348202]
```

Comment: Even more simply: 3, 18, 105, 612, 3567, 20790, 121173, 706248 are divisible by 3;  Dividing by 3 yields 1, 6, 35, 204, 1189, 6930, 40391, 235416 = OEIS A001109 = solutions of $8x^2+1=\Box$, and square roots of square-triangular numbers.  (Naturally the A106328 comments include this connection with A00109.)